# Metafor : Using provided confidence intervals

Tags: r, analysis, meta, medical, metafor

I have been running a meta analysis using Metafor. 
I have been able to extract odds ratios, confidence intervals, sample sizes from 14 articles.

This is the code I have been using:

`data <- read.csv(file="OR.csv", check.names=F,sep=",")`
`dat=data`
`random = rma(OR,SE_X,data=dat)`
`forest (random)`
`funnel (random)`

My issue: The confidence intervals generated by the rma function are greatly different to the ones provided by the author.  This is clearly an issue and I want to use the confidence intervals provided by the articles rather than the ones generated by RMA.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Thank you

S

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of the `rma()` function is for the **sampling variances**. However, you are setting it to `SE_X`, which appears to be the **standard errors**. So, you should use `rma(OR, sei=SE_X, data=dat)`.

However, if `OR` really represents odds ratios, then this isn't right anyway. One would construct the CIs for the log odds ratios and then back-transform (i.e., exponentiate) the interval bounds. Assuming the standard errors you have are also for the log odds ratios, then you would want to do:

```
random <- rma(log(OR), sei=SE_X, data=dat)
forest(random, atransf=exp)
```